# Highcharts - Pie chart with negative values

Tags: javascript, graphics, highcharts, statistics

Is there any way of avoiding this unusual behavior in Highcharts?

It happens when we **update** the chart with negative values on pie (donut) charts. Not on load.

[image: Highcharts pie with one of the gauges showing a werid behavior]

Comment: Can you recreate it as live demo? Cause [donut](http://jsfiddle.net/cu46k6by/) seems to working fine with negative values.

Comment: It's only when we update the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [github thread](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3623) this should be fixed in the newest master branch.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have negative values in the data that you are displaying, use a bar chart instead of a pie chart. Pie charts are supposed to represent a part of a total, a part-to-whole relationship, thus negative numbers won't work because you can't have a negative part of a total.

In case that you actually want to just show that value, try wrapping it in an absolute value;

```
 plotOptions: {
     pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           formatter: function() {
               return this.point.positive ? this.y : this.y * (-1);// <-- or wrap in absolute Math.abs(this.y)
           },
           color: 'black',
           style: {
              font: '13px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/r69127pq/)**